# Firestore security rules based on individual documents?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my Google Firestore collection, I have a series of documents. Each of these documents have their own data. Included in each of these documents is a field called `api_key`;

Using Javascript, how would I make it so that a `set/update` command can only be accepted if the command properly includes the value in `api_key`. Using the `api_key`, the script should be able to `set/update` any content within that document tree... and only that document tree.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  Maybe you could expand on this by offering up some queries that should be allowed or denied in various cases, compared do some actual document contents.

Comment: I want people to be able to edit their documents through javascript, but only if they include the `api_key` matching the field within that document. There is no code I could give to explain it better.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear to me what you meant by "document tree".  That's not a term that Firestore uses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible currently (without using a deprecated expression, which is strongly discouraged), because security rules don't allow you to distinguish between a value provided for a field in a document update, and the value of an existing field with the same name.  It's tempting to try this to try to compare the provided value with the existing value:

```
allow update: if "apiKey" in request.resource.data
    && request.resource.data.apiKey == resource.data.apiKey;
```

But when you say `request.resource.data.apiKey`, that will evaluate to *either* the existing field value in the document, *or* the provided value.  So, if someone simply didn't provide apiKey in the update, the security rule would just provide the existing apiKey value, and the write would be allowed.  This rule would just reject writes where the apiKey is provided by doesn't match the existing value.